# Прослушивание звуковых файлов (.mp3, .ogg, .wav и т.д.) в PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

Возможно ли прослушивать звуковые файлы прямо в PyCharm без использования сторонних программ?
Есть ли какой-нибудь плагин для этого?

Comment: Вообще-то PyCharm — это немножко не медиапроигрыватель. Если вам нужно, чтобы в _программе_ которую вы пишете на PyCharm что-то воспроизводилось, то надо было так и писать. Вообще наверняка полно всяких библиотек на эту тему. Но встроенных питоновских таких точно нету.

Comment: @Глеб Нет необходимо именно прослушивание файлов в самом PyCharm

Comment: Так не бывает ¯\_(ツ)_/¯